# ASP.net Applications not displaying the grand total into grid view control with WCF service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, gridview

I am trying to display the grand total into asp.net web applications by using grid view control. I am using WCF service to retrieve the data form data base by using ID(Account Number). I used the Row Data Bound event to calculate the total but problem is **not displaying the grand total.**

Here is the WCF code.

```
public DataSet DepositDetails(Current_Account_Deposit_Details current_Account_Deposit_Details)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Current_Account_Deposit where Account_Number=@Account_Number", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account_Number", current_Account_Deposit_Details.Account_Number);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            sda.Fill(ds);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            return ds;
        }
```

Here is the code for web applications.

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyService.HalifaxCurrentAccountServiceClient my = new MyService.HalifaxCurrentAccountServiceClient("NetTcpBinding_IHalifaxCurrentAccountService");

        MyService.Current_Account_Deposit_Details cd = new MyService.Current_Account_Deposit_Details();
        cd.Account_Number = TextBox1.Text;

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = my.DepositDetails(cd);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();



    }
    int totalDeposit = 0;
  

    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        // Loop thru each data row and compute total unit price and quantity sold
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            totalDeposit += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Amount"));
           
        }
        // Display totals in the gridview footer
        else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "Grand Total";
            e.Row.Cells[1].Font.Bold = true;

           

            e.Row.Cells[3].Text = totalDeposit.ToString();
            e.Row.Cells[3].Font.Bold = true;

           
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the screen shot of the result.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to get the number of rows in the datagridview?

If so, try dataGridView1.Rows.Count to get the total number of rows.Then use the control to display it.

Here is the reference: [DataGridView.RowCount Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowcount?view=net-5.0#examples)

Comment: This is windows form application. As you can see this asp.net web application

Comment: This is the asp.net web application gridview: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrowcollection.count?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thanks you for suggestions but the link you provided I already seen it . For me the data source is provided by the wcf service not sql data source. This is difficulty I am facing

Comment: I try to use row bound event but did not work

Comment: You can try to use sqlcommand.ExecuteScalar() in the wcf service to get the number of records that meet the conditions, and then use the wcf service to get this value.